# Edit data by Pentaho dashboard

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, dml, pentaho-cde

Is it possible to edit data in database by Pentaho dashboards?
I want to do dashboard where data will be presented in table with edit buttons. 
When button will be pressed, the form will appear in modal window filled by data. User will change and press ok, and this changes affects to database.
 
I haven't found anything related, all I found was just present data, not change.

thanks

Comment: In Pentaho Dashboard i think you will **not** be able to manipulate data. Whereas, Pentaho DI (kettle) provides you steps to update the database tables. So if you are looking to integrate DI with Dashboard, then all you need to do is to execute the Pentaho Kettle from the dashboard everytime a button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the table editor sparkl plugin

Comment: Thanks, Codek. I have already done this. But before, I tried with kettle jobs like Rish said, and it works. Pentaho table editor also works like this.